# Need help to fetch [ITEM_NAME] inside <td> using jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

```
<td class="item" valign="middle" align="left" width="55%">
     <a href="product.asp?itemid=[ITEM_CATALOGID]">[ITEM_NAME]</a>
```

I want to get [ITEM_NAME],for this i have save [ITEM_NAME] in hidden field varible.But i am able to get only last [ITEM_NAME] i added.

I want all the [ITEM_NAME],After that i have to use this condition:

```
if (itename.indexof('custom')) && Total>500
{
//show popup here
}
```

please help:

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = [];
$("table a").each(function(a, b){
    values[a] = b.text;
});
alert(values);
```

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94Da7/).

Comment: I don't understand your question. This will grab all <a> tags and get its value. If your table has a different layout you should post an example on your question.

Comment: But in your question you said "I want all the [ITEM_NAME]". This does that: if you have `<a href="x/y/z">Text</a>` it grabs "Text". If you want to choose a specific <a> tag you have to say what makes it specific...

Comment: Hi salem i want to  get all [ITEM_NAME] means if first time i added item in cart like "Text" (<a href="x/y/z">Text</a>) and second time i added item is "custom"(<a href="x/y/z">custom</a>).Then i have to check condition on both.Simply i need to get both "Text" and "custom"

Comment: If you see the fiddle, there I have 3 links with Value1, Value2 and Value3 inside the anchor tags, and they all get selected! So if this is not waht you're looking for update your question with a better html example, and the values you want to select there.

Comment: Hi salem Fiddle link is not opening please check?

Comment: @rishi jsfiddle was down. You can check now.

Comment: Hi Salem i checked it now,i use same code but there are 3-4 tables in my html so i use table id like this:    
var values = [];
$("#tblitem a").each(function(a, b){
    values[a] = b.text;
});
alert(values);
 but in this table there are some other <a> tags .so if i will give id to <a> then what will be the syntax??

Comment: it almost work but i want to use only <a> tag that have [ITEM_NAME].